# Firebase custom domain with facebook authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Facebook authentication not working with custom domain on firebase.

```
        fbRef = new Firebase("https://my-app.firebaseio.com/")

        facebookCallback = (error, authData) ->
            if error then console.log 'Login Failed!', error
            else console.log 'Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData

        fbRef.authWithOAuthRedirect 'facebook', facebookCallback, {scope: 'email'}
```

I set up Facebook authentication and custom domain name with firebase (really nice setup experience by the way!) but now the authentication works from `localhost:8080` and `my-app.firebaseapp.com` but it does **not** work using `www.my-custom-domain.com`.

There is some redirection going on and the url gets appended with `https://www.my-custom-domain.com#?&__firebase_request_key=........` and then the hash query parameter disappears but I'm not logged in.

I'm I missing something in the docs?

Comment: Did you add your custom domain to the list of Authorized Domains for OAuth Redirects in the Login & Auth tab of your Firebase's dashboard?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, thank you :) My misstake! Maybe it could be worth mentioning a line on "Authorized Domains for OAuth Redirects" in this docs page: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html. That's were I looked and didn't find anything. Although, it is pretty obvious when you click Login & Auth and choose the Facebook tab in the control panel.